# "Proceeding" as an adjective

Tags: adjectives

I thought I've heard it being used as such before, but I cannot seem to find any dictionary (online) that details it as an adjective.

We normally use "precede" and its derivatives to talk about events that happen before, e.g. "The preceding event was lunch."

"Proceed" is a reference to events in the future, so I was wondering if we could use it as such: "The proceeding event is dinner."

Is there no such usage for the word and I'm just making it up?

Comment: Do you mean "proceeding" or "preceding"? You used both in your question.

Comment: I only used "preceding" in the example because I was wondering if "proceeding" can be used in the same way (but with the meaning being, "after" as opposed to "before" for "preceding").

Comment: No, they have different meanings: "proceeding" means 'continuing' or 'in progress' whereas "preceding" means 'happening before'.

Comment: No, you can't use it like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it is used as an adjective. There is no example available in ***[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=proceeding%20event&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cproceeding%20event%3B%2Cc0)*** for the expression you are suggesting: "proceeding event". Adjectives normally used would be "next" or "following".

[Proceeding](http://www.yourdictionary.com/proceeding):

- It is  a verb and  a noun.